# Search string for letters with js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a search through a string for letters as I type. 
I tried something like this but its not giving me the correct result. 
Leaving out the typing code I just want to do a match.

```
var str = 'Hello World';
var expr = /ol/i;
const result = str.search(expr);
console.log('result = ', result);
```

The result is -1; but the letters ol are in the string ? 
The only way I can get it to work is if I use the letters in sequence like

```
var expr = /lo/i;
```

Comment: `ol` is not a substring of `'Hello World'`, so there's no match.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it so it checks for any order or every letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split what you're searching for into characters, and then check whether `.every` one of them are included in your input:

```js
const input = 'Hello World';
const inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
const charsToFind = 'ol'
  .toLowerCase();
if ([...charsToFind].every(char => inputLower.includes(char))) {
  console.log('all chars are included');
}
```

If you want more efficiency, you can use a Set instead (`Set.has` is `O(1)`, `String.includes` is `O(n)`):

```js
const input = 'Hello World';
const inputLowerSet = new Set(input.toLowerCase());
const charsToFind = 'ol'
  .toLowerCase();
if ([...charsToFind].every(char => inputLowerSet.has(char))) {
  console.log('all chars are included');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

search both letters separately and combine the boolean results.

str.indexOf() see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

or

str.includes() see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for occurrence of characters in a RegEx, you would want to wrap those characters in [brackets]. Your code, when modified as such, will return 2 as the result, because the first hit of either "o" or "l" is at index 2.

http://regexr.com/4ff2d

```
var str = 'Hello World';
var expr = /[ol]/i;
const result = str.search(expr);
console.log('result = ', result);
//result =  2
```

Comment: This will only check whether *at least one* of the characters exists in the string.